# What does !+ mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

After taking over a project from someone else, written in Javascript.
One line I see everywhere is if statements using `!+msg`. From testing I can see that it checks to see if there is more than one word or not, but I was hoping someone could explain why this works. Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to give a contextually informative answer because nobody knows what sort of value `msg` might contain, or why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+` operator coerces its operand to a number, and the `!` operator coerces its operand to a boolean value and inverts its sense (`false` -> `true` or vice-versa). Thus `!+msg` means, "if the value of `msg` interpreted as a number is 0 or `NaN`, the value should be `true`, otherwise `false`."

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!